# Substitute for window.event

Tags: javascript, html, tablet

It seems that `window.event` doesn't function in mobile devices, but it is fine when using in a computer.

Can anyone tell me, is there any substitute for `window.event`, so that the commend can be activated on mobile devices?

Comment: How are you using `window.event`? Can you share the code?

Comment: *"is fine when using a computer"* ... well that depends on which browser is used. It is not a global in all browsers

Comment: `window.event` is an Internet Exploder kludge, that, for some inane reason Google added to Chrome, thereby validating it's existence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event):

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

See [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) which expects the second argument to be:

> listener 
>   The object which receives a notification (an object that implements the Event interface) when an event of the specified type occurs. This must be an object implementing the EventListener interface, or a JavaScript function.

And the description of [the EventListener interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener):

> Parameters
>
> event
>   The DOM Event which was triggered.

So, in short:

```
eventTarget.addEventListener("click", yourFunction);

function yourFunction(evt) {
    // use the local evt variable 
    // do not use the global, non-standard event variable
}
```

Comment: My code is:

If (window.event){
keycode=event.keycode;
}else}
Keycode=e.keycode;
}

How can I change the code, so that it is suitable for mobile devices?

Comment: Can I use console.log ('event'+evt) instead of window.event ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

## Use `arguments[0]`

Example snippet:

```css
ib {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.618em;
  border-radius: 0.618em;
}
.emphasize {
  /* make it really obnoxious */
  font-size: 2em;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ib style="background:#f88;cursor:pointer"
    onclick="arguments[0].target.closest('ib').classList.toggle('emphasize')">
  <p>Two inner blocks:</p>
  <ib style="background:#8f8">
    <p>One inner block:</p>
    <ib style="background:#88f">
      <p>First paragraph</p>
      <p>Then 2nd paragraph</p>
    </ib>
  </ib>
</ib>
```